# How to root my ASUS Eee Pad Transformer?

Tags: rooting, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I need to root my Eee Pad Transformer. But how?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial on my TF101 http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-tf101-development/31927-frederuco-s-guide-root-rom-tf101.html and it works By the way, are talking about the TF101 ?

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: Download & install [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), connect your device, and start ADB:

```
$ cd /var/tmp; wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz
$ tar xvfz android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz
$ cd /var/tmp/android-sdk-linux
$ ls
add-ons  platforms       samples         system-images  tools
docs     platform-tools  SDK Readme.txt  temp
$ cd platform-tools
$ ls
aapt  aidl     dx   llvm-rs-cc  renderscript
adb   dexdump  lib  NOTICE.txt  source.properties

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:0821 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0b05:4e1f ASUSTek Computer, Inc.

$ ./adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting in USB mode
```

As of this stage, it shows one icon in your system tray.

**Step 2**: Enable USB debug mode

Click the system tray, wireless icon, Settings and go to `Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging`.

**Step 3**: Play?

```
Tablet
     Power off
       [Press volume up + power button for 5 seconds]
       [Screen should stay off, its normal]
        So i did trace behind whats was happening such as USB is alive or dead?
       $ lsusb
       Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
       Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c05d Logitech, Inc. 
       $ lsusb
       Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
       Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c05d Logitech, Inc. 
       Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0955:7820 NVidia Corp.  << Screen is off but USB is up
       [now launch the BASH script]
```

[Screen 1]

```
##########################################
# lynx http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1198303
# Copy the universal-V3.tar file to somewhere safe place for reuse
###################################################################
$ cd /home/sun/Downloads/me; 
$ wget http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=677456&d=1312486060
$ tar xvf universal-V3.tar; cd universal;
$ sudo ./universal.sh

Asus Transformer TF101 Universal Root
===================================================
Disconnect your tablet from usb (if connected) and turn it off (if it's not).
Press and hold the UP Volume and the power button for ~5sec.
For now the tablet screen should stay off, it's perfectly normal
Now connect to usb
Press any key when you're ready.
Nvflash started
rcm version 0X20001
System Information:
   chip name: t20
   chip id: 0x20 major: 1 minor: 3
   chip sku: 0x8
   chip uid: 0x033c20c143608197
   macrovision: disabled
   hdcp: enabled
   sbk burned: true
   dk burned: true
   boot device: emmc
   operating mode: 4
   device config strap: 2
   device config fuse: 0
   sdram config strap: 0

sending file: transformer.bct
- 4080/4080 bytes sent
transformer.bct sent successfully
odm data: 0x300d8011
downloading bootloader -- load address: 0x108000 entry point: 0x108000
sending file: bootloader.bin
| 943193/943193 bytes sent
bootloader.bin sent successfully
waiting for bootloader to initialize
bootloader downloaded successfully

Making a backup of your boot and recovery partitions in tf101-backup-20111112143317... 

Nvflash started
[resume mode]
receiving file: ../tf101-backup-20111112143317/boot.img, expected size: 8388608 bytes
/ 8388608/8388608 bytes received
file received successfully
Nvflash started
[resume mode]
receiving file: ../tf101-backup-20111112143317/recovery.img, expected size: 5242880 bytes
/ 5242880/5242880 bytes received
file received successfully
Unpacking boot.img...

Writing kernel to boot.img-kernel.gz
Writing ramdisk to boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz
Writing boot.img config to boot.img-config
4351 blocks
Modifying default.prop...

Repacking as my_boot.img...

Cleaning up...

All Done!
Your new boot image is my_boot.img


Write back the modified boot partition... 

Nvflash started
[resume mode]
sending file: my_boot.img
- 4214784/4214784 bytes sent
my_boot.img sent successfully

ClockWorkMod (CWM)
=====================================
ClockWorkMod recovery is a recovery image that let's you do some funny things like make a nandroid backup, installing custom rom and much more
This is not necessary for root

NOTE: if you install CWM you won't be able to update your tablet with the OTA firmware from ASUS, until you revert back to the stock recovery

Do you wish to install clockworkmod recovery? [y/N]n
```

[Screen 2]

```
Now press and hold the power button for ~10sec.

Your tablet should reboot. When android is fully loaded, go to Settings -> Applications -> Development and make sure USB Debugging is enabled.
Press any key when you're ready.
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
remount succeeded
612 KB/s (26324 bytes in 0.041s)
1262 KB/s (196521 bytes in 0.152s)
```

[Screen 3]

```
Done.
Your tablet is now rooted.

Enjoy!.


$ ./adb shell
# su
#
```

That works! You're now rooted.